# How to install X11 development libraries on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: xorg, 19.04

I'm trying to install [leandvb](http://www.pabr.org/radio/leandvb/leandvb.en.html), but the GUI won't compile, because I (apparently) don't have X11 development libraries. How do I install these?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends what the author means by "X11 development libraries". Probably it will be sufficient to install the `libx11-dev` package:

```
sudo apt install libx11-dev
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

EDIT: How does one know these things? Is there a way to find out, or is this something you "just know"? :-)

Comment: I think one way could be to use https://packages.ubuntu.com/ if you know the header file names, by selecting "source package names" on the dropdown near the search bar there. If you know the header file names you are looking for of course.

Comment: You can also install and use `apt-file` to search for packages that contain a given file

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev xserver-xorg-dev xorg-dev
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1169523)

Comment: From what I can see xorg-dev is an empty package... is it useful only because it has dependencies on some obscure files?